# Orbeon 4.3 doesn't seem to allow creation of new form with given ID

Tags: orbeon

We have an application that creates new form runner forms in Orbeon. This is done by opening the URL to the form runner form.
Example:
http://server.com/orbeon/fr/[APP_NAME]/[FORM_NAME]/new/[new id]

In 3.8 and 3.9 we where able to give the [new id] and Orbeon would create a new form with the given ID. 
In 4.3 however it doesn't seem to accept the [new id] any more.
We get this message in the browser:
You do not have access to this page.

It does allow us to generate new forms by using this url:
http://server.com/orbeon/fr/[APP_NAME]/[FORM_NAME]/new
But this doesn't give us control over the ID anymore.

We use the standard Exist persistence layer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the differences between 3.4 and 4.3, but in 4.3 the id can be passed as a URL parameter and then set using an action.

For example:

```
http://server.com/orbeon/fr/[APP_NAME]/[FORM_NAME]/new?document-id=[new id]
```

and include an action in the form definition:

```
<xf:model>
    ...
    <xf:action id="populate-document-id-binding">
        <xf:action ev:event="xforms-ready" ev:observer="fr-form-model" if="($fr-mode='new') and (xxf:get-request-parameter('document-id')!='')">
            <xf:setvalue model="fr-parameters-model" ref="instance('fr-parameters-instance')/document" value="xxf:get-request-parameter('document-id')"/>
        </xf:action>
    </xf:action>
    ...
</xf:model>
```

This assumes you're happy with editing the form definition source.

DISCLAIMER: I don't know the road-map for the document parameter, so can't say how supportable this is going forward.

Comment: If your happy, can you please mark the answer as correct/recommended?